# Correct approach to Add or Edit with CoreData Managed Objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data

A common scenario is to have a view that allows to Add or Edit an underlying model,
we could simply source the view with a `initWithObject:(MyManagedObject*)object` and
create a new one if `object` is nil.

Now when leaving the view, we can ask the `ManagedObjectContext` if it is dirty, but how do we know if it is dirty because the `object` was modified, or due to some other `objects` that may have been modified someplace else?

And if we want to provide the user with a `cancel` option, how would one `rollback` the changes on only the current `object` (and delete the `object` if it was just newly created in this view?)

Is it advised to use multiple `ManagedObjectContext`s? (One for each view? -- in this case synchronization may become an issue, no?) Or should one use the `UndoManager`? Can this be achieved using `undoGroups`?

Comment: Is this for iOS or OS X?

Comment: The problem originated (for me) on iOS, but I don't see how it's iOS specific.

Comment: You've got a lot more opportunity to modify other objects in an OS x app - in iOS, you present a modal view controller and the user is locked into it until they dismiss, which makes your problem a lot easier to solve.

Comment: @jrturton that's right. Though here I may also run into concurrency issues, if the MO in question in modified in the background while the view is open.

Answer (score 2):

There are three common ways that I am aware of. And most certainly I would love to hear other people to post how they've dealt with this.

**Undo Groups**
Before presenting a detailed view controller modally (with a save and cancel options), I create an undo group and then create an managed object instance in a managed object context and do the preliminary setup.

On the delegate methods for save and cancel I end undo groups and with cancel I also do a undoNestedGroup.

Good: You can undo edits with ease.
Bad: If there are certain actions beyond that you would not want to cancel, it's going to be very tricky. In other words its a cancel all or nothing approach.

**Manual Handling**
This is really viable when adding a new item, since it's too hard to track individual edits. It basically means that in your delegate method for cancel you delete the object you know you added before presenting the detailed view controller.

**Draft Contexts**
This means you'll create another managed object context instance which you either merge back to the main context or throw away with all the changes. As you said, the merging part can be somewhat pain, but it's entirely doable. Compared to undo groups approached this has the benefit of merging back only the changes that you save. So, while still a bit tricky, you can better fine-tune, what changes you want to keep and which you want to cancel.

With iOS5 Apple added nested contexts where you can create a child context easily for the detailed view controller to use and either just save or throw it away. No extra code is necessary to take care of the merging of contexts.

Good: You keep your main context untouched from all modifications until you are ready to save.
Bad: Its more complicated to implement prior to iOS5 (which introduces nested contexts which is awesome).

Best regards,

sven.